# Delphi - COM/OLE starting example needed

Tags: delphi, dll, com

10 years have ellapsed since I used COM/OLE, and I forget 90% of them.
Now we need to make a COM object to access some data from PHP/Python (this is specific thing, the php ODBC don't access the output params of a DataBase - like stored proc output), and my idea the I realize a minimal object with one method, and PHP/Python can call this to get the output...

```
procedure ExecSQL(Config, IP, Port, DBName, SQL, IDFieldName : variant) : output
output is [IDValue, ErrorMsg, HResult]
```

Please help me a very little example, how to start it?
I need only this, but I'm confused by many ActiveX/COM in the palette.
What I need to use to make a simple COM DLL, and how to register my COM object with this DLL?

Thanks:
   dd

Comment: It would help if you'd let us know what version of Delphi you are using

Comment: Sorry... This is Delphi 6 Prof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For COM related applications in Delphi this link is usefull http://www.techvanguards.com/

Answer (score 6):

1. Select File\New\ActiveX Library - this creates ActiveX DLL project
2. Select File\New\Automation Object - this creates the type library and implementation
3. Using the type library editor, add methods/properties to the interface
4. Write implementation code
5. Select Run\Register ActiveX Server - this registers the COM server DLL

Comment: I would use Regsvr32 to register the COM server, that works on every machine. `regsvr32.exe "path and filename of my com-server"` (add /u to uninstall).

Comment: regsvr32 does exactly the same thing as the IDE: loads the dll and calls its exported DllRegisterServer function.
On Vista and higher, however, you may need to run this from an elevated process which the IDE is probably not.

Comment: I know, but to install the COM server with the IDE you have to have the IDE installed. That's why I recommend regsvr32, because I don't think the development machine = webserver.